# Compass is not shown on map view of Osmdroid

Tags: overlay, osmdroid, compass

I've used the Osmdroid tutorial to display compass overlay on the map view as follow, but the problem is that it does not show the compass.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        map = findViewById(R.id.map);
        map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        setView(12, new GeoPoint(35.68, 51.38));

        /* compass part */
        CompassOverlay comOverlay = new CompassOverlay(this, new InternalCompassOrientationProvider(getApplicationContext()), map);
        comOverlay.enableCompass();
        map.getOverlays().add(comOverlay);
    }
```

Comment: What the call `comOverlay.enableCompass();` returns? It should return `true`, when an initialization of the sensor was successful. If it returns `false`, there was an error during initialization and no compass would be shown.

Comment: @JosefAdamcik, it returns false. But what's the reason?

Comment: It means, that required sensor is unsupported and/or unavailable on the device. It may also mean, that the application doesn't have a permission to use the sensor, but AFAIK there shouldn't be any permission needed for this kind of sensor. Osmdroid uses Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION internally (which is deprecated, but should still work and works on android 8.1). Are you sure, that your device has a compass? Are you able to run any other application that uses orientation / compass successfully?

Comment: @JosefAdamcik, I applied orientation sensor data for other applications on my device before and it worked perfectly. Also, there is no permission needed for these type of sensors to be included in the manifest.xml.

Comment: As I thought. Unfortunately  that leaves me clueless. The [InternalCompassOrientationProvider](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/compass/InternalCompassOrientationProvider.java) is just simple wrapper around Android's sensor manager API. The [CompassOverlay](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/compass/CompassOverlay.java) class isn't complicated either.  (Links are to the source, so you can check it yourselv).

Comment: What I would do to debug the problem: 1) Check the library version and source code version. 2) step into library's code with debugger and confirm that there's really a problem with sensor initialization and not another problem.

Comment: 3) Double check that the device is ok with the particular way how the sensor is used-> simple propotype app, copy and paste snippets of library code to an activity and just try if it works. [Or you can use this activity I created in order to test it myself.](https://gist.github.com/josefadamcik/1a890b9b62afa52572c320b878c88d7e).

Comment: 4) There is a [similar issue recorded](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/1060). Its author claims, that the problem was deprecated Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION and he managed to fix it by implementing its own IOrientationProvider. He didn't share his code, but this might be a path to explore.